# unexpected behavior of delete_if and reject! methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of elements in Ruby

```
nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
```

The task is to remove some duplicates in-place if element occures in array more than twice.

I wrote following code:

```
nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3]

def remove_elements(nums)
  nums.delete_if{ |num| nums.count(num) > 2 } #reject! returns the same result
end
```

So i expected this result

```
[2,2,3]
```

But got

```
[2,3]
```

However `reject` method returns expected array

```
def remove_elements(nums)
  nums.reject{ |num| nums.count(num) > 2 } # returns [2,2,3]
end
```

Comment: That’s because `nums.delete_if` modifies `nums`, thus changing the result from `nums.count`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the way `delete_if` / `reject!` (and their counterparts `keep_if` / `select!`) work internally. Let's take a look at another example which removes even numbers while printing `nums` at each step:

```
nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def remove_elements(nums)
  nums.reject! do |num|
    p nums: nums
    num.even?
  end
end

p result: remove_elements(nums)
```

Output:

```
{:nums=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
{:nums=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
{:nums=>[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
{:nums=>[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
{:nums=>[1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
{:nums=>[1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
{:nums=>[1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
{:result=>[1, 3, 5]}
```

As you can see, `nums` is being modified in a seemingly strange way. But what happens here exactly?

Instead of creating a temporary array, Ruby's implementation re-uses the existing array to store the result. As it is traversing the array, it copies each element that should be kept (for which the block returns a *falsy* result) to the front, overwriting any existing element. In the end, the array gets truncated to its final size: (ASCII art ahead)

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 ┌──┘
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    ┌─────┘
[1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
       ┌────────┘
[1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[1, 3, 5]
 ───┬───
  result
```

Note that `1`, `3` and `5` occur twice in the array intermediately. That's why your `nums.count` doesn't work as expected – you're counting elements while the array is being restructured.

---

To solve this problem, you could count the elements in advance, e.g. via [`tally`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally):

```
nums = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

counts = nums.tally
#=> {1=>3, 2=>2, 3=>1}

nums.delete_if { |num| counts[num] > 2 }
#=> [2, 2, 3]
```

This is also faster because you don't have to traverse the entire array for each element again in order to count it.